# Is it possible to open an Active Director or Exchange Management Console user dialog directly from Powershell?

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010, powershell

I'd like to be able to launch either the AD user dialog, or the EMC mailbox dialog directly from a Powershell script to open a specific user. The workflow goes something to the effect of "Does everything look correct on this user? Y/N" to continuing on, or to bringing up the account to edit.

[image] [image]

There's no reason to completely duplicate the functionality of these dialogs. I don't mind requiring that EMC or ADU&C already be open before the script is run, if necessary.

Comment: There is some automation that can be done VBS.  MMC has a snapins object that might be able to do what you are asking.  A bit more about it here.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa815049(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: so your positing that it's somehow simpler to invoke a com automation model to try to automate the MMC dialogs than it is to simply display the information (even in WPF)??  I suspect it would be far easier to use normal PowerShell methods.

Comment: It's not displaying the information that's the issue... it's allowing the user to **edit** it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what information you need you could do something like the following in powershell

```
get-aduser <username> -properties <comma separated list of properties> | out-gridview
```

You can't edit things in that view, but if you're just verifying that things look right it might do the trick. If you wanted to get really fancy you could roll that into a script to take input from a CSV or something else and do multiple users at once.

Comment: Something very similar to this is exactly what I use in the 'Does everything look correct' step. The problem is not viewing but editing. I need a way to allow the user to correct errors that are found; programming an interactive editor in PowerShell is impractical.